# How to fade out a page then direct to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was just wondering how to fade out a page then open up another html page. Right now I have:

```
<div class="close" onclick="window.location.href='../index.html';">
    <div class="lr">
        <div class="rl"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
          $('.close a').click(function() {
            var destination = this.href;
            $('body').fadeOut(2000, function() {
                window.location = destination;
              });
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
    </script>       
</div>
```

I want it so that when "close" is clicked, the page fades out then then opens up my index.html page?

Currently my code is not working :(.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $('.close a').click(function() { change to  $('.close').click(function() {

Comment: Yea you dont have `a` in you `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="close" data-link="https://www.youtube.com">
    <div class="lr">
        <div class="rl">LOREM IPSUM DOLORs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    var destination = $(this).data("link");
 $("body").fadeOut(1000,function(){
       window.location.replace(destination);
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably the `replace` bit, try using the part that's in the original code. http://tinyurl.com/ovzsdjk

Comment: First do this `data-link="index.php"`, second make sure your path to file is correct and last are you sure you included `jquery` correctly?

Comment: I am testing on my localhost and its working, strange but i couldn't save this example on jsfiddle for some reason, every time i fork it or updated it, it just opens new fiddle

Comment: Probably has to do with sandboxing and not allowing dynamic external link changes. Looks like more or less the same thing happens on Codepen. Should be fine on a "normal" live site.

Comment: The jQuery library is missing - you can pick it by clicking on the cog icon above the JS field. Then it might be a better idea to place the snippet in that field as well. Like this, it's parsed *before* jQuery itself. But check the link in the third comment, it is working there apart from not redirecting because of site restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a tag in your html. This code should work.

```
    <div class="close" onclick="window.location.href='../index.html';">
        <div class="lr">
            <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
              $('.close').click(function() {
                var destination = this.href;
                $('body').fadeOut(2000, function() {
                    window.location = destination;
                  });
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
        </script>       
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not... it keeps just loading up the index.html page with no fade.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript has an extra closing bracket and closing parenthesis. You are also missing your `a`

```
<div class="close">
<a href="/index.html">Click Here</a>
<div class="lr">
    <div class="rl"></div>
</div>
<script>
     $(function() {
         $('.close a').click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var destination = this.href;
             $('body').fadeOut(2000, function() {
                 window.location = destination;
             });
         });
         return false;
     });
</script>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4wz9uqwd/

Comment: Still not working. It keeps loading up the index.html page with no fade.

Comment: Did you try the JS Fiddle? Make sure you are including Jquery in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).bind("unload", function() {
 });
 $("body").css("overflow", "scroll");
 $("body").fadeIn(2000);
 $("a.transition").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 linkLocation = this.href;
 $("body").fadeOut(1500, redirectPage);      
 });

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
});
```

Live example:

www.damianodesign.com

Comment: This means, you need the preventDefault if you click a link.
Don't use the inline JS.
This is the smoothest I could come up with, looks good even on mobile.